# Does the seed function in numpy and random work need to be set in every module?

Tags: python, numpy, random, random-seed

I am calling

```
np.random.seed(seed)
random.seed(seed)
```

in the `__main__` module `foo.py`. That module calls out to another module `bar.py` that also uses results from `np.random` and `random`. Does the latter also need to set the seed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Using `np.random.seed(...)` sets a global random state.

Usually this is not desirable.  You may prefer to use a `np.random.RandomState()` instance in your code, so that you don't also seed the PRNGs for all other library code within your runtime.